# Manga where the protagonist takes in orphan sisters

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don’t remember much. Main character takes in three orphan sisters (the youngest is cheerful, the middle is shy but serious and calm, and the oldest is caring). I don't recall if they're blood related. Main character takes them in since the oldest wants to go into town to earn money so she can pay the MC for letting them stay at his house. They are surprised that the MC knows magic. I think it was an isekai, not sure.

Comment: Is there any romance (or sex) between the MC and the sisters?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *Tensei Kenja wa Musume to Kurasu*, also known as *The Reincarnated Sage Lives With His Daughters*.

The main character is reincarnated into another world, and makes his home in an abandoned church. A teacher, or nun, from a nearby academy that was attacked come by with 3 orphaned girls. However, the oldest was the serious and calm one, the middle was cheerful, and the youngest was shy. All of them care for each other.  The teacher from the academy wanted to go live in the nearby city to make money for the orphans to live with the main character.  The teacher and sisters were all surprised that the main character could use magic without chanting.